# How to print Stack elements from first to last

Tags: c++

This will add 5 numbers to the stack and print them in reverse

> Input: 1 2 3 4 5
>
> Output: 5 4 3 2 1

How can I make it print from 1-5 ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void print(stack <int> s)
{
    while (!s.empty())
    {
        cout << " " << s.top();
        s.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    stack <int> s;
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cin >> n;
        s.push(n);
    }

    print(s);
}
```

Comment: Use a regular array or `std::vector` instead, and iterate over it in any order you want.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know how to do it with vector or array, but can it be done with stack?

Comment: @Gosho Do you know how stack works? The Last In, First Out principle? That's the way. When you push elements on stack, you will pop them them in reverse order.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `std::stack`?

Comment: if you have to use a stack then use a vector as well. pop the stack elements into the vector and then loop over the vector.

Comment: @Kit. Yes, a hint would be nice.

Comment: @Kit. it is ok.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your assignment wants you to reverse the stack. You can search the internet "reverse stack in c++" and find many solutions.

A simple and crude solution of `void print(stack<int> s)` is provided below:

```
void print(stack<int> s){
    stack<int> temp;
    while(!s.empty()){
        temp.push(s.top());
        s.pop();
    }
    while(!temp.empty()){
        cout<<" "<<temp.top();
        temp.pop();
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Algorithm behind this solution is very simple. It creates a temporary stack and pushes each element of stack s in it. Now it iterates and print all the elements.

More optimized and well written code can be found over internet.